# Add material at the bottom of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking

I would like to add vertical material at the bottom of footnotes. I expect this will involve checking if `\footins` is non-empty just before a pagebreak (`\ifvoid\footins\else …`) and conditionally inserting the vertical material (`… \insert\footins{\vspace{1cm}}\fi`). However, I can't seem to find the right command to patch; I tried modifying `\@makecol`, and `\@opcol` from LaTeX's `\output` routine (`\let\old@makecol=\@makecol\renewcommand\@makecol{\ifvoid\footins … \fi\old@makecol}`) with no success.

The following picture illustrates my motivation. There is a footer, above the footer there are the footnotes and above the footnotes there is the body text. When footnotes exist, I would like to raise them by a small amount as indicated by the red arrow.

[image: An image showing the footer, and the footnotes]

The following MWE based on [GuM's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434052/70941) typesets the document in the above picture.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% The fancy page style:
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

This should be a page without footnotes.

\lipsum[1-4]

Here we place a footnote.\footnote{This one.}  Then we add more text.

\lipsum[5-15]

A long footnote occurs here.\footnote{\lipsum*[16]}.

\lipsum[17-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words, and an MWE, twice that, to show what you are attempting.

Comment: The footer material comes after the footnotes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I added a picture as a quick fix. I will try to construct a good MWE.

Comment: Does every footnoted page have this requirement, or does it only occur in one particular page?

Comment: In every footnoted page as a part of a template.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes … and now the MWE is also in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret correctly your question, you simply want to add some space below the footnote (and obove the footer).  Try the following (explanations are in the comments):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\WitikoAdditionalspace
\setlength\WitikoAdditionalspace{1cm} % you said so

\makeatletter

% Add our additional space to the space to subtract from the page goal on pages 
% where at least one footnote occur:
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\WitikoAdditionalspace}

% Patch the output routine (without "etoolbox"):
\gdef \@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \unvbox \@cclv
       % Only the amount of space originally devised by LaTeX should go above 
       % the footnotes:
       \skip@ \skip\footins
       \advance \skip@ -\WitikoAdditionalspace
       \vskip \skip@
       % (We could also say
       % \vskip \dimexpr \skip\footins -\WitikoAdditionalspace \relax
       % but let's keep the LaTeX kernel independent of eTeX extensions...)
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \footnoterule
         \unvbox \footins
         % Add our space below the footnotes:
         \vskip \WitikoAdditionalspace
       \color@endgroup
       }%
   \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}

\makeatother

% The fancy page style:
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

This should be a page without footnotes.

\lipsum[1-4]

Here we place a footnote.\footnote{This one.}  Then we add more text.

\lipsum[5-15]

A long footnote occurs here.\footnote{\lipsum*[16]}.

\lipsum[17-20]

\end{document}
```

**Addition:**  Answering [@Witiko’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434013/add-material-at-the-bottom-of-footnotes#comment1088304_434052), no, there is no particular reason to avoid eTeX extensions or the `etoolbox` package.  However, since the patch doesn’t come down to a simple substitution of one token or two, it could be safer to write down explicitly how the patched macro should look like.

Here’s an example that uses `\patchcmd` and **`\glueexpr`** (*not* `\dimexpr`!):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\WitikoAdditionalSpace
\setlength\WitikoAdditionalSpace{1cm} % you said so

\makeatletter

% Add our additional space to the space to subtract from the page goal on pages 
% where at least one footnote occur:
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\WitikoAdditionalSpace}

% Patch the output routine with "etoolbox":
\patchcmd{\@makecol}
    {\vskip \skip\footins}
    {\vskip \glueexpr \skip\footins -\WitikoAdditionalSpace \relax}
    {\typeout{1st patch succeeded.}}
    {\typeout{1st patch FAILED!}}
\patchcmd{\@makecol}
    {\unvbox \footins}
    {\unvbox \footins \vskip \WitikoAdditionalSpace}
    {\typeout{2nd patch succeeded.}}
    {\typeout{2nd patch FAILED!}}

\makeatother

% The fancy page style:
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

This should be a page without footnotes.

\lipsum[1-8]

Here we place a footnote.\footnote{This one.}  Then we add more text.

\lipsum[9-15]

A long footnote occurs here.\footnote{\lipsum*[16]}.

\lipsum[17-24]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there a greater cosmic reason for doing things without etoolbox / eTeX? I feel the answer would be easier to understand if it just patched the two lines instead of containing the entire `\@makecol` without clear separation of new code versus source2e.

Comment: I took the liberty to incorporate your MWE into the original question, so that there is a greater correspondence between the question, and your (accepted) answer.